# PHP mail() not delivering mail when I've a url in the message body

Tags: php, sendmail

I don't understand why when I try to send a mail using PHP mail function, I don't receive any mail when there is a url with variables in the body of the message such as
http://www.chicmaker.com/fr/xxx.html?id_client=2 ?
Any idea or clue ?

Comment: Without that url the mail is delivered? If so, show the code plz.

Comment: putting some code would be nice:-)

Comment: almost certain to be hitting a spam filter somewhere along the line. Unlikely to be anything you can do about it from within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting a spam filter that checks whether there's reason to believe that the links are owned by the sender. You should make sure that the domain part of all your links corresponds with the sender email domain. For example:

```
http://www.chicmaker.com/fr/xxx.html
```

should correspond with:

```
noreply@chicmaker.com
```